# Array Index Out Bound when spliting the string

Tags: java, split

I have a list of data sotre inside my txt file which will look like the following

```
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"
```

I will read all the input inside my txt file and store into `DailyFileData`. After that,I would like to extract out the `IP address` and `gmail.com` from the data but I cant make it happen.The `mail1` variable will store  `"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"` from the txt file I had search for multiple solution for how to specify two delimiter in stackoverflow and others website. But I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfboundException` .The error occur in the following line of code

```
String IP1 = Emaildata1[1];
```

Here is my source code

```
 for(int c = DailyFileData.size()-1;c>=0;c--)
       {
        String mail1 = DailyFileData.get(c);
        MailCount1 = Collections.frequency(DailyFileData,mail1);
        System.out.println("Count of mail is :"+MailCount1);
        String filename1 = f.getCanonicalPath();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher( (CharSequence) filename1);
         while (match.find()) 
        {
           date1 = match.group(0);
        }
         String [] Emaildata1 = mail1.split(CSVSplitBy);
         System.out.println(Emaildata1);
         String domain1 = Emaildata1 [0];
         String IP1 = Emaildata1[1];
         String [] domainArray1 = domain1.split(emailSplitBy);
         String domain2 = domainArray1[0];

         System.out.println("The extracted domain is :"+domain2);
         System.out.println("The extracted date is :"+date1);
         System.out.println("The extracted IP is :"+IP1);
         domainAndCounting1.add(domain1);
         domainAndCounting1.add(String.valueOf(MailCount1));
             Iterator<String> it = DailyFileData.iterator();
                     while(it.hasNext())
                          {
                            String mail2 = it.next();
                            if(mail2.equals(mail1))
                               {
                                 it.remove();
                                 c--;
                               }
                          }
            }
```

Comment: what is the value of `mail1` ?

Comment: mail1 is the variable which store ip address and email id

Comment: Yes,mail1 will store IP and email address, I had attached with my full code

Comment: Maybe you show us how your mail1 variable looks before it is splitted. Because what you suggested: "abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34" is not a valid string. It are two strings separated by a comma.

Comment: Try to System.out.println your DailyFileData.get(c) on each iteration. In this way you can see if there is any of the strings not responding to the two tokens structure you're assuming to manage.

Comment: Please rewrite this as a [mcve]. Almost none of your code is relevant to the problem you're having - anything after the exception won't be executed, so won't be relevant to why the exception is occurring. You should check whether the string you're splitting is the one you expect - if it is, then how you get it is irrelevant. If it's not, then the splitting part is irrelevant. Basically, you need to do the diagnostic work to narrow down the problem - and then edit your question with a [mcve] of *just* that part. You may well solve the issue while you're doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve in your code. But if you have `String` like `"abc@gmail.com","10.9.2.34"` and you are trying to extract the `IP address` and domain name only `gmail.com` you can simply try below approach without going to any complication of pattern matching:

```
String a = "\"abc@gmail.com\",\"10.9.2.34\"";
        String arr[] = a.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        for (String aa : arr) {
            if (aa.contains("@")) {
                System.out.println(aa.substring(aa.indexOf("@") + 1, aa.length() - 1));
            } else {
                System.out.println(aa.substring(1, aa.length() - 1));
            }
        }
```

N.B.: This is not best solution. This is just solve your small problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I manage solved my problem, it's due to some careless mistake I make in the code